# MySQL SELECT 1 Parent many Children values

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have one parent with many children and I would like from the parent Id selecting value from 3 children, if it's possible.

[image]

I tried this

```
SELECT children1.value1, children2.value2, children3.value3 
FROM children1, children2, children3

JOIN ... Some code ...

WHERE parent.id = 1;
```

I've tried to write the JOIN with no success ...

Comment: ... also [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: `FROM children1, children2, children3 JOIN ...` is no way to JOIN, you are mixing the old comma join syntax and the newer JOIN syntax... Which can be error prone (errors about missing tables/aliases for example) when mixing the older syntax with the newer ideally you should join with the newer syntax only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.value1, c2.value1, c3.value1 
FROM parent p 
LEFT JOIN children1 c1 ON c1.idParent = p.id 
LEFT JOIN children2 c2 ON c2.idParent = p.id
LEFT JOIN children3 c3 ON c3.idParent = p.id
WHERE p.id = 1
```

`LEFT JOIN` is an assumption though.

Answer (score 4):

The correct syntax of [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) is:

```
...
FROM Table1
<INNER|LEFT|RIGHT> JOIN Table2 ON <JOIN conditions>
WHERE...
```

So your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT Parent.Id, children1.value1, children2.value2, children3.value3 
FROM Parent
JOIN children1 ON Parent.Id = children1.idParent
JOIN children2 ON Parent.Id = children2.idParent
JOIN children3 ON Parent.Id = children3.idParent
WHERE parent.id = 1;
```

You can change the type of `JOIN` (i.e. `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN` etc) according to your table structure.

Comment: The old ANSI/ISO comma join is also still valid syntax, as it is never removed from the standards.. Anyhow it is harder to read and more error prone when mixing join styles like the topicstarter did..

Comment: `<INNER|LEFT|RIGHT|FULL> JOIN ` -> One note MySQL does not support `FULL` join..

Answer (score 0):

I would not make the assumption that each of the "children" table has only one child for a given parent.  It would seem that `union all` makes sense in this case:

```
select c.isparent, 1 as which, c.value1
from children1 c
where c.parentid = 1
union all
select c.isparent, 2 as which, c.value2
from children2 c
where c.parentid = 2
union all
select c.isparent, 3 as which, c.value3
from children3 c
where c.parentid = 3;
```